# jQuery datatable theme not applied on jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, datatables

Just playing with different JQuery themes and controls. I'm trying to implement datatable example and apply default theme available [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html). I've been unsuccessful so far.

Need some help to understand why this is happening. I've also attached a screen shot of page.

```
<%-- 
Document   : ctsUserRegistration
Created on : Dec 13, 2015, 11:02:12 PM
Author     : nishad
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>User Registration</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


    <style>
        div.dataTables_wrapper {
            width: 1100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Nishad Joshi <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>                  
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Forms</a>
                    </li>                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Home <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Administration</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Office</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>  
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Operations <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo1" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Advocates</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Clients</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Courts</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Registrar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Case Category</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Case Stage</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Documents</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li> 
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> Case <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="demo2" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Case Updates</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Case Documents</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Notice Information</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Allocate Cases</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Payments</a>
                            </li>                               
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            User Registration
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>  <a href="index.jsp">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> User Registration
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <form role="form">
                            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Position</th>
                                        <th>Office</th>
                                        <th>Age</th>
                                        <th>Start date</th>
                                        <th>Salary</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Position</th>
                                        <th>Office</th>
                                        <th>Age</th>
                                        <th>Start date</th>
                                        <th>Salary</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                                        <td>System Architect</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>61</td>
                                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                        <td>$320,800</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                                        <td>Accountant</td>
                                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                                        <td>63</td>
                                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                                        <td>$170,750</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                                        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>66</td>
                                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                                        <td>$86,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                                        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>22</td>
                                        <td>2012/03/29</td>
                                        <td>$433,060</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Airi Satou</td>
                                        <td>Accountant</td>
                                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                                        <td>33</td>
                                        <td>2008/11/28</td>
                                        <td>$162,700</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                                        <td>New York</td>
                                        <td>61</td>
                                        <td>2012/12/02</td>
                                        <td>$372,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                                        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>59</td>
                                        <td>2012/08/06</td>
                                        <td>$137,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                                        <td>55</td>
                                        <td>2010/10/14</td>
                                        <td>$327,900</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                                        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>39</td>
                                        <td>2009/09/15</td>
                                        <td>$205,500</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                                        <td>Software Engineer</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>23</td>
                                        <td>2008/12/13</td>
                                        <td>$103,600</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                                        <td>Office Manager</td>
                                        <td>London</td>
                                        <td>30</td>
                                        <td>2008/12/19</td>
                                        <td>$90,560</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                                        <td>Support Lead</td>
                                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                        <td>22</td>
                                        <td>2013/03/03</td>
                                        <td>$342,000</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                                        <td>Regional Director</td>
                                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                                        <td>36</td>
                                        <td>2008/10/16</td>
                                        <td>$470,600</td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                        </form>
                        <script>

                            $(document).ready(function () {

                                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                                    "sScrollX": "500%",
                                    "sScrollXInner": "110%",
                                    "bScrollCollapse": true

                                });


                            });


                        </script>
                    </div>




                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

        <!-- /#wrapper -->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[JSP Form screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRdtI.jpg)

Comment: too many jQuery and bootstrap script `src`es.

Comment: Are you observing any error in console?

Comment: no... I know there are too many src es. I'm just trying to apply datatable theme to my current form and design.

Comment: Hi everyone... I badly need help with this one. SOS!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#example").DataTable({columnDefs:[{targets:[0, 1, 2, 4, 5], width:"300px"}]});
                }
                    );
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:76%">
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                        <td>System Architect</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                        <td>$320,800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Accountant</td>
                        <td>Tokyo</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$170,750</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Bindrid, It worked well. I applied other themes on top of the datatable.... Thank you very much. Only thing I'm struggling with now is column width... Text is wrapped (column names as well as content). This is causing row height to increase...

Comment: My experience with DataTable is that it column balancing is not the best.  more often than not, I end up putting the table inside a div with its width set.  Then  I set the column widths on most of the columns, often all but one. the results have been satisfactory for me.

Comment: I edited my example so you can see what I mean.  You will see that I set the same widths for all columns except age, with causes it to be much smaller.

Comment: Hi Bindrid - Thank you very much for all the help. It worked well.